# `js` trigger submits an empty object error

Tags: jsx-a11y

`js` trigger submits an empty object error

```js
 <input hidden  type="text" id="flag" name="flag" value="${model.flag}" >
```

```js
$('input[value="submit"]').hide();
    $('#bt-yes').click(function () {
        $('#flag').val("1")
        $('input[value="submit"]').trigger()
    })
```

errorInfo:

```
Uneaught TvoeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Comment: $('input[value="submit"]'), value="submit" or type="submit"?

Comment: `value="submit"`

Answer (score 0):

`.trigger` To pass the event name, change to

```
$('input[value="submit"]').trigger('click')
// or
$('input[value="submit"]').click()
```